# TypeError: map is not a function (Using React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am having some issues trying to map an array that sits within a json object in a mongo db collection. All of the schema data is being passed through the state and is available on the page I am tying to map the question array.

Any help on firstly how I can access the questions within the question array and how I can look to map the array contents would be greatly appreaciated.

Db schema

```
const QuizSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    quizName: String,
    quizTheme: String,
    shortDescription: String,
    longDescription: String,
    question: [{
        question1: String,
        question2: String,
        question3: String,
        question4: String,
        answer: String
    }]
})
```

back end controller

```
export const getQuestions = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const questions = await Quiz.findById(id);

        res.status(200).json(questions);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

front end action

```
export const getQuestions = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: 'START_LOADING' });

    const { data } = await api.fetchQuestions(id);

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_QUESTIONS', payload: data });
    dispatch({ type: 'END_LOADING' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

reducer

```
case 'FETCH_QUESTIONS':
      return { ...state, questions: action.payload };
```

React component

```
const Questions = () => {
  const { questions, quiz, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.quiz);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log(questions)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getQuestions(id));
  }, [id]);

  if (!questions) return null;


  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <Paper elevation={6} className={classes.loadingPaper}>
        <CircularProgress size="7em" />
      </Paper>
    );
  }



  return (
    <Paper style={{ padding: '20px', borderRadius: '15px' }} elevation={6}>
      <div className={classes.card}>
        <div className={classes.section}>
          <Typography variant="h3" component="h2">{questions.quizName}</Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="body1" component="p">{questions.quizTheme}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1">{questions.longDescription}</Typography>
          <Divider style={{ margin: '20px 0' }} />
          <Typography variant="body1"><strong>Questions</strong></Typography>
          <Divider style={{ margin: '20px 0' }} />
          {questions.map((question) => (
            <Card elevation={6}>
              <Grid>
                <p>{question.question1}</p>
              </Grid>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default Questions;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means `questions` is not an array yet when you do the `map` on it, you can try this trick :

```
{questions && questions.map((question) => (
            <Card elevation={6}>
              <Grid>
                <p>{question.question1}</p>
              </Grid>
            </Card>
          ))}
```

This will check if `questions` is defined before doing the `map` on it

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What would be the best way to access the question array within my Quiz schema and output via a map function?

Comment: You succeeded to access the question array no ? And can you show your ```getQuestions``` function ?

Comment: No I am struggling for the correct way to access the array. I have updated now with the api calls that is getting the correct data to my component which is outputting in the console log which I have also now added above. Eveything looks fine data wise with the state just really struggling on how to firstly access the array of questions within the quiz object and then how to output the contents of this nested array onto the component. Not sure if I need to destructure questions to a const that is the array and then map that but not sure best way or if that would even work.

Comment: what's the name of the whole object ? ```questions``` ? if so, you have to do a ```questions.question.map()```

Comment: Sadly this is giving error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined. Not sure why it is undefined when console.log(questions)  gives the full object.

Comment: and if you do a ```console.log(questions.question.map(question => question._id)``` you don't get the different ids ? that's weird

Comment: That console.log brought it up so thank you, and now all of a sudden its not giving me the error despite not changing any of the code. Mega confused but happy. Thanks for your time and effort have a good one.